# username in accesstoken with identityserver4

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm protecting an API using identityserver4. I tried to add ClaimTypes.Name where I create the ApiResource and also tried to add userclaims to GrantValidationResult when user is authenticated in IdServer. As a sidenote I'm using ASPNET identity together with IDServer.
I read a bit about IProfileService, but not sure it's needed to "just" get the username included in the access_token. Does someone know where to configure the name claim and get it passed together with the access token?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the interface ICustomTokenRequestValidator.

This is how I have added the custom fields in token.

```
public class DefaultClientClaimsAdder : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
    {
     public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
     {
         context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Client.AlwaysSendClientClaims = true;
         context.Result.ValidatedRequest.ClientClaims.Add(new Claim("clientid", "testingtesting"));
         return Task.FromResult(0);

     }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay got it working. I added an implementation og IProfileService to identityserver and added profile to the requested scope

Comment: Can you pleas share to code to put username on access token? I am tried few thing but nothing is working. Thanks